# JS. Событие "onbeforeunload" при закрытии вкладки сразу после открытия вкладки

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, opera

Добрый день!

Никто не знает почему не срабатывает js-событие "onbeforeunload", если у страницы не было фокуса? Т.е. если открыть страницу с кодом

```
<script type="type/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  return "Окно 1";
};
</script>
```

и, если на странице не было фокуса (т.е. не кликали на неё мышью), то при закрытии вкладки (через крестик на вкладке) ничего не произойдёт.

Нажатие на F5 вызывет событие, т.к., скорее всего, при этом страница всё-таки получает фокус.

Это как-то связано с политикой безопасности? Или всё-таки есть способ обойти это ограничение и вызвать это (или другое) событие при закрытии вкладки без получения фокуса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это сделано намеренно. На мобильниках оно совсем не работает. А там где работает, выводит стандартный для браузера текст, а не возвращаемый функцией.

В firefox'е есть параметр `dom.require_user_interaction_for_beforeunload` значение которого по умолчанию `true`. Из-за этого параметра `onbeforeunload` сработает только если пользователь кликнул или прокрутил страницу.

Другого стабильно работающего способа сделать что-то перед закрытием страницы нет.